# Insert default values in SQLite2

Tags: sqlite

How to crate a now row without knowing the any of the columns of the table and using default values therefore?

In sqlite3 I simply do:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "text" TEXT DEFAULT "hello world");
sqlite> INSERT INTO t DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t;
1|hello world
```

But in sqlite2.8.17 I get:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO t DEFAULT VALUES;
SQL error near 'DEFAULT': Syntax error.
```

Is there a way to do this right in sqlite2 or do I need to give the values manually in the insert statement?

Comment: sqlite3 is now 9 years old. I just wonder why would you want to use sqlite2 today?

Comment: I have to use a stupid hosting provider which supports PHP5 but no sqlite3.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify at least one value; all the others will then get their default values.

The `rowid` automatically gets a value when you specify `NULL`, so you can use that one:

```
INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES(NULL);
```